# Deploy to Google AppEngine using Heroku

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku

I have made a program on Heroku that takes data from Dropbox and processes it to give plain .html files that can be used as a static website. But hosting on Heroku is not what I want to do. I want the static website to be hosted on Google AppEngine and let Heroku manage the processing.

On my local PC, I use [this method](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Free-Static-Page-Hosting-on-Google-App-Engine-in-a-5-minutes.html) to host static files on AppEngine. How can I achieve this on Heroku so that it automatically processes the source files and publishes it to AppEngine? Is this even possible?

I am using AppEngine due to better performance in static hosting and good free quota.

Comment: You have to update your appengine project to change static files. You can use the Google App Engine Admin API to deploy a new version.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the [Google App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/). The Admin API allows you to programmatically manage your application. I am going to assume you are talking about deploying to only a single App Engine application.

The general process that you would need to follow is:

1. Create a [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) project if you don't already have one set up for this project.
2. [Enable the Admin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appengine/overview) on this project.
3. [Create your OAuth credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials). Depending on your deployment you will either want an OAuth client ID or a service account. If you are implementing your API calls on the server side and need to deploy the App Engine app to the same project as this console project that you're currently working with, then a service account is easier. If you are going to deploy instead to a user's project that isn't the same as this Admin API project, then you need an OAuth client ID.
4. At this point, you're going to need to start coding your administration app. The best place to go now is into the Admin API docs and follow the procedures there. Broadly your steps from this point forward will be:

   1. Set up your authentication with the API. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/accessing-the-api) here give very generic curl commands, but your flow will differ if you use a service account. Suggest using a [Google Client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/client-libraries) for your programming language in any case to help.
   2. Create a Cloud Storage bucket to hold your staged files for deployment.
   3. Write the code that will call the API and point to this Storage bucket and will also create an API representation of the app.yaml configuration file. [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-apps) are language generic but explain this.
   4. [Shift traffic to your newest version of the app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/migrating-splitting-traffic).

Comment: do you know of some examples that might help?